# stm32h563 Microcontroller power dissipation

Tags: microcontroller

interface of Microcontroller- STM32H563  with Quad SPI -Flash W25Q16JV . AND Microcontroller with I2C -TMP102 (2nos) slave device on the same I2C i/f,Power dissapated for major power consuption Component and type of cooling planned, how to calculate power dissipation for each device.

Comment: Why would the MCU source any current to those devices? They should have a power supply.

Comment: What unit(s) do you use in your software?

Comment: @Antonio51 What units you mean and how would the used units would make a difference here?